# Google AppEngine, Django and request.FILES

Tags: python, html, django, google-app-engine

**Situation**: An html form (with the method="POST" and enctype="multipart/form-data" attributes set properly) is submitted to the server, which is Django on Google's AppEngine. It contains a file input, which is moved (not cloned) into said form and submitted through an iframe. For small files (~1mb or less) the submitted files are being found in the request.FILES dictionary, and stored in a blob. For files above 1mb, however, the look into request.FILES is returning an error, claiming the key (which is the name of the file input element) is not found in the given dict, and in fact that the request.FILES (and request.POST) dicts are empty.

**Question**: Is this due to a AppEngine limitation (if so, is there a workaround?) Is this related to Django in some way (do note that the enctype and method are set appropriately)? Is there some other element that is missing?

**Additional Information**: Please also note that I am a javascript programmer filling in for an absent Python programmer, and know only the basics. Please tailor your answers accordingly.

**Relevant Python:**

```
def media_image_upload(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      img = request.FILES['img']
```

**Relevant html:**

```
<form id="hiddenUpForm" style="display:none;" action="http://localhost:8080/media/imageUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upTarget" method="POST">
  <input name="img" id="img" type="file" accept="image/*">
  <iframe id="upTarget" name="upTarget" src="" style="width:0;height:0;border:0px solid #fff;"></iframe>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that in order to upload files that are larger than 1 MB, you need to use the Blobstore API to create a special URL that is used for the upload; it can't be your regular <1 MB URL.

The controller code that generates the HTML page that contains the upload form would use `upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('media/imageUploadBig')` and would then add `upload_url` to your template values and render the template.

The template, in turn, would contain a FORM definition something like this:

```
<form id="hiddenUpForm" style="display:none;" action="{{ upload_url|safe }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upTarget" method="POST">
```

This means that you either need to have two different forms -- one for files that are less than 1 MB and one for files that are larger -- or you can store all of your images in the Blobstore.

See the [Blobstore docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html) for more information.

Comment: I believe we are already using the blobstore for this purpose, creating a model `class Image(models.Model):` which has a property `data = BlobField()`. Moreover, the html page from which the form is being submitted is static - is templating required in order to implement this functionality? Or can I create and access this special url from a static page?

Comment: Sane, the Blob data type that is part of the datastore is very different from the Blobstore. In the datastore, a Blob is a 1Mb sized chunk of binary data. The Blobstore allows you to overcome that 1 Mb limit, but you have to use its mechanisms, as I described in my answer. Yes, templating will be required to generate a page that contains the URL that is produced by the `create_upload_url` call.